# LDAP Auth with checking the group user belongs to?

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, mod-auth-ldap

Here is the problem I want to solve.

We have a mercurial source control server (Linux + Apache + mod_auth), that I want to configure so it works against LDAP (right now it's basic authorization on apache with passwords stored in .htpasswd files). I put developers in OU with name "Developers"

```
'OU=Developers,DC=us,DC=domain,DC=com'
```

the problem is that we have various projects and some of them should restrict access only to certain developers. I can put a different OU inside developers, but I can't have the same user account to be present in multiple OUs. At the same time I don't like to have multiple accounts per user (harder to manage in future)

SO I'm thinking is it possible to authorize against OU and certain logical group?

Like I created OU "Developers" and then created several windows groups - like ProjectA, projectB, projectC and assign developers to those groups as well.

Is it possible to configure LDAP base dn, so it looks for group as well?

thanks,
Dmitry

Comment: What's your LDAP auth configuration look like currently?

Comment: I don't have it yet. Right now it's setup against mod_auth that uses basic htaccess/htpasswd files and I'd like to switch to LDAP.

Comment: Looks like this is possible according to this tutorial: http://its.virginia.edu/websupport/limitaccess.html

Comment: Right, you'll use `Require ldap-group` - but do you need to authorize against the OU as well, or just check group membership?

Comment: I need to authorize against OU (higher level) and then against group I do believe to make sure they have access to certain project only

Comment: Would it work to set a search base of the OU, then check for group membership on the results from that?

Comment: yes - this is exactly what I'm looking for. First - against OU and then group memebership :) Now I need to figure our correct vhost config :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we've got users in an OU at `OU=Developers,DC=us,DC=domain,DC=com`, then certain locations need to have specific group memberships as well - something like `CN=ProjectA,OU=Developers,DC=us,DC=domain,DC=com` as a group.

Something along these lines should do the trick..

```
<Location />
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "user message on login"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    # This is your LDAP server configuration - if you can, use SSL (which requires
    # configuring either an LDAPTrustedGlobalCert or to set LDAPVerifyServerCert Off)
    # The search base DN is included here.
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap-server.example.com:636/OU=Developers,DC=us,DC=domain,DC=com?cn"
    # This is the user account that will be used by Apache to bind to LDAP for auth checking.
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=ldapserviceaccount,OU=Developers,DC=us,DC=domain,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "passwordhere"
    # For just the / location, we'll force a valid login (any user account in the OU)
    Require valid-user
</Location>
<Location /project-a>
    # And here we'll configure a specific group for this location
    Require ldap-group CN=ProjectA,OU=Developers,DC=us,DC=domain,DC=com
</Location>
```

Comment: Shane - thank you very MUCH~! I will try it and let you know my results!

Comment: Shane, why do we need the following variables in config?

 AuthLDAPBindDN &   AuthLDAPBindPassword

Comment: okay clear Active Directory doesn't allow anonymous binds. This is why you have to specify the AuthLDAPBindDN and AuthLDAPBindPassword directives

Comment: @DmitrySemenov Yup, that's right.  Since it's AD, you might want to also use `?sAMAccountName` instead of `?cn` as your user id attribute.